# Ceramic texture looks right in evee but not cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing

So I'm trying to make like a ceramic matcha bowl and I think i found a way of making a nice looking ceramic texture but it's not displaying right when I render it in cycles it looks like it lost all it's details.

Here is my render in evee [image]

And this is my render in cycles. [image]

Does anyone know what is happening? This is my shader for the pot btw [image]

Comment: hello, maybe share the object? https://pasteall.org/blend/